# Multi lingual support for Android 7.0 and above does not work

Tags: android

Starting in Android 7.0, Android language and locale support for multilingual users was improved.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html

But it does not work exactly what I thought.

Here is res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tistory.httphckim999.languageprioritytest.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/first_test" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/second_test" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/third_test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Language Priority Test</string>
    <string name="first_test">first default</string>
    <string name="second_test">second default</string>
    <string name="third_test">third default</string>
</resources>
```

Here is res/values-ko/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="first_test">first ko</string>
</resources>
```

Here is res/values-zh/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="second_test">second zh</string>
</resources>
```

And here is res/values-ja/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="third_test">third ja</string>
</resources>
```

And my test devices locale setting priority is "ko > zh > ja"

I think it should be print like this.

**first ko**

**second zh**

**third ja**

But it was printed like this

**first ko**

**second default**

**third default**

I can't understand why it was printed like this.

I upload my test project here.

https://github.com/kimhc999/LanguagePriorityTest

I tested it in Galaxy S7(7.0), PIXEL(8.0 Preview 3), and emulators(7.0, 7.1, 8.0). But all of them have same result.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: It won't show 3 languages. Your device is ko, then you app shows the ko

Comment: @YanbinHu They say, they support multi language setting start Android 7.0 and I set "ko>zh>ja". But show only one language?

Answer (score 1):

It is working in expected way, you are perceiving it in wrong way. In your app default language is English and you placed all values in strings.xml as following

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Language Priority Test</string>
    <string name="first_test">first default</string>
    <string name="second_test">second default</string>
    <string name="third_test">third default</string>
</resources>
```

Language of your phone is **ko** and you placed only 1 value for that

Here is res/values-ko/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="first_test">first ko</string>
</resources>
```

When you run the application it will first search for value in **values-ko** folder and if value isn't available there then default value will be picked from values/strings.xml which is english in your case.

As only first_test is available in values-ko so for second_test and third_test it will pick values from default values folder and you are getting right result:

**first ko**

**second default**

**third default**

Comment: Then, is it mean, if my device could not found "values-ko", then it will search for "values-zh" and then, will it shows only "zh" and "default"?
Is it mean my device can show only one locale and default?

Comment: No, if device could not found values-ko then it will show default directly .

Comment: Thank you. But I wonder what is this document mean? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html
Please see "table 3" in this link. This document say they also care second user setting locale starting Android 7.0. And I tested on 7.0, 7.1, 8.0 preview.

Comment: Try by removing values-ko from the app and see what happens

Comment: Yes. I saw. That's why I upload this question. What android official document say and what my machine show is different. I write this question because my code does not run like what document say.

Comment: what you got in result?

Comment: **first default** 
**second default** 
**third default** 
I got this. But if [Android Official Docuement table 3](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html) is right, then I think after remove values-ko it should be show **first default** **second ja** **third zh**. Is this document wrong??

Comment: If in version 7 and above it is not behaving in described way then it might be missing some essential thing.